# How to simulate the failure of MFC based GUI functions in Unit Test?

Tags: windows, mfc

How to simulate the failure of Dialog Box, Window Creation Functions and other MFC System Functions in a Unit Testing Environment?

Are there any tools or frameworks available?

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to use Application Verifier (free, Microsoft) with its "Low Resource Simulation" mode. It doesn't have any stubs for UI functions, but it can fake failures in certain Win32 APIs such as memory allocation, wait primitives, etc.

Another idea is to use a full-blown mock framework for C++. One such framework is Isolator++.